# Chrome + another process: interprocess communication faster than HTTP / XHR requests?

Tags: javascript, python, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, ipc

I have a process #1 doing realtime image processing on a video stream.

I need to render this video in a HTML page in Chrome (process #2 on the same computer), in a `canvas` or `img` or `video` HTML5 element.

Since I have 1000x1000 pixels x 3 bytes RGB, at 20 fps, this is 57 MB/sec to send between process #1 and process #2 (Chrome).

Tested:

- Using PNG, JPG, BMP realtime encoding + `multipart/x-mixed-replace`. It is quite slow, see [Sending RGB image data from Python numpy to a browser HTML page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72703724/sending-rgb-image-data-from-python-numpy-to-a-browser-html-page)
- Sending the raw image bytes with HTTP request is better, but receiving the XHR in JS and doing `putImageData` with so much data is still CPU-intensive, see [Update frames of a video on a HTML page, from incoming raw image data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72712772/update-frames-of-a-video-on-a-html-page-from-incoming-raw-image-data)

**What options are there to send more than 100 MB/sec (in the future case 2000x2000 pixels video 20fps) from a process #1 to process #2 (Chrome) on the same computer?**

Can Chrome access some data of process #1 directly without having to send/receive via a HTTP bottleneck? Is inter-process-communication with **shared memory** possible between process #1 and Chrome?

Can this be done at a Chrome extension layer?

NB: Process #1 is written in C++ or Python

Comment: The new WebTransport API, probably.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you can use websocket connection for this task. It will be opened only one time, and then you can send lots of data through it with huge reduction of traffic usage (in comparation with http requests).

You can check basic description and examples [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSocket).